# Redirection Loop. Not able to get into the root cause

Tags: redirect

Here are my pages:

Login Page: if user login info is valid, redirect to destination URL(ex: https://int63.xyz.co.uk/base/page/mydetails.jsp) else display login page

LoginServlet Page: if user has an open session, redirect to the proper resource else redirect to login page

Destination URL: It redirect the request back to the Login Url which then makes it a repetitive call.

In the above scenario when I clear my browser history and cache and then hit the target page it gives me the login page as expected. But when I enter correct details it goes into an infinite loop(That's what I can capture in logs).

The request is getting successfully authenticated on login page and sent across loginservlet page well. But I am unsure about what processing is made at the application end and why it redirects back to the login page.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

We dont use any .htaccess file instead we follow the mechanism of Identity and Access management wherein we create junctions and control the access to them through ACLs.

Comment: Post your current .htaccess rules

Comment: Sorry anubhava I dont know where to find them. I work on tools for bypassing the security framework I am not clear about the application side settings involved. We have ACLs for accessing any page and decision are taken on that basis.

Comment: But then how do you think anybody can guess it from outside?

Comment: Can you please let me know where to find .htaccess rules. It would be much appreciated. I was hoping to get some commonly made mistakes which might suggest me to get into the root. Still I dont think we use any .htaccess files we use ACL for controlling the access. Its much more realted to Identity and acces management. Sorry not to be clear in question.

Comment: .htaccess is usually in the root directory of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help provided on this issue.

I figured out what was the problem with this.

When I said it was making a redirection loop it was because of cross domain request forwarding. It was authenticating the users on abs.com and was sending the request to some abs.co.uk so the page on abs.co.uk was not able to recognize and was sending the request back to abs.com which again forwarded the request to the same page as it has already authenticated this user.

So this cross domain forwarding of request was a reason of this loop which I then made changes to get it worked in same domains.